# PDO query, INT not going into query via binding

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm very new with PDO queries, usually with strings everything goes into the DB how i desire it to be updated but somehow the random value **:health** is not subtracted from the INT value **health** in the database. whereas **cooldown** is correctly updated.
what am i doing wrong?

```
$account_health = 100;

if (isset($_POST['action1'])) {
    if($action1 == 2){
        $health_hurt = $account_health/5;
        $health = rand(0,$health_hurt);
        $session_username = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
    // query
    $q = "UPDATE `users` SET `cooldown`=(`cooldown`+'120'),`health`=`health`-':health',`cool`=NOW(),`action`=NOW() WHERE `username`=:username;";
    $st = $db->prepare($q);
        $st->bindValue(':health', $health, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->bindValue(':username', $session_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $start = $st->execute();
    echo "<div align='center'>$health</div>";
    exit;
    }}
```

Database:

```
column - Type - default value
cooldown [INT 255] [0]
health [INT 255] [100]
cool [DATETIME] [0000-00-00 00:00:00]
action [DATETIME] [0000-00-00 00:00:00]
```

Comment: Remove quotes from `':health'`

Comment: Thank you for your help, however that gives the error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in /home/name/domains/domain.nl/public_html/build/pages/members/page_action.php on line 102` which is in this case `$st->bindValue(:health, $session_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: IN your question you bind health as INT so what`s happening?

Comment: Dude i said remove quotes in the query not in bindValue `health-':health'` Here

Comment: Thank you Mihai ! that did the trick :) ... i've invested hours looking into that. thank you so much!